# calculated field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document is as below.

```
{
    "name" : "MadhuA"+i,
    "lastname" : "MohanB"+i,
    "created" : new Date(),
    "Address" : [
        {
            "Home Address" : "St:123, Abcd road, cityA, stateB, Pin code123",
            "Work Address" : "St:134, xyz road, cityV, stateX, pin code456",
            "Billing Address" : "St:156, pppp road, cityZ, stateNm ,Pincode154"
        }
    ],
    "tariff" : [
        {
            "Service" : "Broadband",
            "Recurring" : "Monthly",
            "Fee" : 100
        }
    ],
    "charges" : [ {
            "charge_details" : [
                {
                    "start_date" : "01-JAN-2016",
                    "end_date" : "01-FEB-2016",
                    "charge_amount" : Math.floor(Math.random()*400),
                    "Status" : "Outstanding",
                    "Service" : "Broadband",
                    "charge_type" : "monthly"
                },
                {
                    "start_date" : "01-JAN-2016",
                    "end_date" : "01-FEB-2016",
                    "charge_amount" : Math.floor(Math.random()*400),
                    "Status" : "Outstanding",
                    "Service" : "VoIP",
                    "charge_type" : "monthly"
                }
            ] }
        ]
}
```

I want the Total amount to be populated with all the charge_amounts in the charges field. Whenever there is a charge_amount added to the document, the total_amount should be changed accordingly.
Please let me know if we have such functionality.

<3

Comment: Can you show what you have at least tried?

Comment: `I want the Total amount` _what_ `Total amount`? You _should not_ want derived values _in_ a DB.

Comment: sum of charge_total with in a document is the Total amount. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to add a property `totalAmount` such that:

1. Contain the list of `charge_amount` values
2. Changes dynamically when the document changes

If this is the case the best solution is to use Mongo 3.4 with views, writing something like:

```
db.createView("totalAmount", "collection", [
  { 
   $addFields: {
       totalAmount:  "$charges.charge_details.charge_amount" 
     }
  },
  { 
   $addFields: {
       totalAmount:  { $arrayElemAt: ["$totalAmount",0] } 
     }
  },
])
```

Here I am assuming that your collection is called "collection"
Now, you can query the new view and you will see the totalAmount:

```
db.totalAmount.find().pretty
```

shows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5856c41fbd0535e2fb8fb2ff"),
    "name" : "MadhuA",
    "lastname" : "MohanB",
    "created" : ISODate("2016-12-18T17:15:11.797Z"),
    "Address" : [
        {
            "Home Address" : "St:123, Abcd road, cityA, stateB, Pin code123",
            "Work Address" : "St:134, xyz road, cityV, stateX, pin code456",
            "Billing Address" : "St:156, pppp road, cityZ, stateNm ,Pincode154"
        }
    ],
    "tariff" : [
        {
            "Service" : "Broadband",
            "Recurring" : "Monthly",
            "Fee" : 100
        }
    ],
    "charges" : [
        {
            "charge_details" : [
                {
                    "start_date" : "01-JAN-2016",
                    "end_date" : "01-FEB-2016",
                    "charge_amount" : 37,
                    "Status" : "Outstanding",
                    "Service" : "Broadband",
                    "charge_type" : "monthly"
                },
                {
                    "start_date" : "01-JAN-2016",
                    "end_date" : "01-FEB-2016",
                    "charge_amount" : 398,
                    "Status" : "Outstanding",
                    "Service" : "VoIP",
                    "charge_type" : "monthly"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totalAmount" : [
        37,
        398
    ]
}
```

Moreover, if you add new documents to "`collection`" or modify any document the view (in particular `totalAmount`) will change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually i want to maintain the sum of the "charge_amount" in totalAmount field. I will try to create a view that can update the field whenever there is a new charge_amount added to document.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error:

```
> db.totalAmount.find({"name" : "MadhuA4097899"}).pretty()
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array, but is int",
    "code" : 28689,
    "codeName" : "Location28689"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, in my case it works perfectly: `db.totalAmount.find({name:"MadhuA"}).pretty()` returns the result as expected